# Fix DataGrid Column Headings When Scroll Viewer is Applied

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, scrollviewer

I have a DataGrid wrapped in a ScrollViewer like this...

```
<ScrollViewer MaxHeight="600" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              BorderThickness="0" Padding="0">
    <sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding BatchItems}" IsReadOnly="True">
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <!-- Yada, yada, yada -->
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

It works fine and the scrollbar appears when it should.  However, when I scroll it down, the DataGrid column headings move up and are no longer visible.  I want to freeze the column headings so that when I scroll down I still know what I am looking at.  How can this be done?

Comment: If you want to scroll just the rows, why not let the DataGrid do its job without the ScrollViewer?

Comment: @Michael How?  I am not sure what you mean.  If I just use the DataGrid, I do not get a scroll bar when there are enough rows to flow over my StackPanel.

Comment: So your DataGrid grows as data is added? Try setting a Height on the DataGrid (and set VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible") to see if that looks like it'll do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Michael You nailed it!  Please add this as an answer so we can give you some rep.

Comment: @Michael I removed ScrollViewer, added a MaxHeight to my DataGrid, and set VerticalScrollBarVisibility to "Auto".  It is working like a charm!

Comment: Eh, you're good; accept your own answer. I just steered you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Michael Todd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16623/michael-todd) for the tips.  I was able to do away with the ScrollViewer completely.  The DataGrid has support for scrolling out of the box, evidently...

```
<sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding BatchItems}" IsReadOnly="True"
              MaxHeight="600" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <!-- Yada, yada, yada -->
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```